# How to use the same variable again in the pandas assign() method?

Tags: python, pandas, dplyr, data-science, data-analysis

I have started learning Python Pandas. So basically I am an R user and heavily use tidyverse. So I am trying to use Pandas in the same manner as the Tidyverse. So I am trying to execute this code which throws me an error.

```
(
    pd.DataFrame(
        {'A':[1,2,3],
         'B':[4,5,6]}
                )
    .assign(A = lambda x: x.A + 1,
            B = lambda x: x.B + x.A,
            A = 1)
    
)
```

*SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated: A*

So how could I use pandas in a `tidyverse` manner? More specifically is there any method in pandas that works like the `dplyr::mutate`?

Comment: what are you trying to do with the second `A=1`? you cannot ever call a function with keyword arguments that repeat... most people who can help answer this question likely have no idea what tidyverse means ... I dont

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One (maybe obvious) approach, could be to use several `assign`:

```
(pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
               'B':[4,5,6]})
   .assign(A = lambda x: x.A + 1,
           B = lambda x: x.B + x.A,)
   .assign(A = 1)
)
```

Another could be to use [`pipe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html) and a function:

```
def process(df):
    df['A'] = df['A']+1
    df['B'] = df['A']+df['B']+1
    df['A'] = 1
    return df
    
(pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
               'B':[4,5,6]})
   .pipe(process)
)
```

output:

```
   A   B
0  1   6
1  1   8
2  1  10
```

Comment: I am net to python. So is there any function which support multiple assignment sequentially?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, function parameters and dictionary keys are unique in python.

Answer (score 2):

Try not pass the re-assign A value

```
pd.DataFrame(
    ...:     {'A': [1, 2, 3],
    ...:      'B': [4, 5, 6]}
    ...: ).assign(
    ...:         B = lambda x: x.B + x.A + 1,
    ...:         A = 1
    ...:         )
    ...: 
Out[154]: 
   A   B
0  1   6
1  1   8
2  1  10
```

In `R` `dplyr` and `tidyverse` assign value with `mutate` two times is not necessary~

When you do `groupby` in `pandas`,

`transform` is almost equal to `group_by` `mutate` in R

`agg` is almost equal to `group_by` `summarise` in R

Comment: This was just a demo problem. There is a certain amount of time required to reassign the same variable.

So I am not looking for an answer to this problem rather I am asking if it is possible to re-assign with the help of some other methods available.

df %>% 
  mutate(specialty = str_remove(specialty,"^\\w+/"),
         specialty = fct_lump(specialty,10)) %>% 
  count(specialty) %>% 
...

This is one of the codes. where I use multiple assigning. Though it was possible to avoid multiple assignment but sometimes it really requires to me